# Need effective way to output from one computer to HDMI + DVI + a VGA projector at once

Tags: multiple-monitors

Here's my problem:

I need to be able to output from one computer to a LCD monitor at the workstation, drive a LCD TV that'll be wall mounted, and a VGA output to drive a projector as well.

Is there any elegant way to do this?   What's the option that will give me the least headaches support-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need all three displays to be mirrored? If not you can just get 2 video cards, one with DVI + HDMI (or dual DVI with an HDMI adapter), and one video card with VGA. If you need them to be mirrored you can get a DVI splitter http://cables.cablesunlimited.com/cables/Dvi%20Splitter and throw an HDMI adapter on one and use the second output of the video card to drive the projector.